# Unable to export data from Cassandra to MySql

Tags: mysql, cassandra, export, sqoop, datastax-enterprise

We are facing problem while exporting data from Cassandra to MySql database.
For example,
1. I have created keyspace called `test_ks` and column family called `test_cf` in cassandra using cql.

I have inserted some dummy data into `test_cf` and corresponding files are created in the folder `/var/lib/cassandra/data/test_ks/test_cf` as shown below.

```
[root@balnsand01 test_cf]# pwd

/var/lib/cassandra/data/test_ks/test_cf

[root@balnsand01 test_cf]# ls -lrt

total 24

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4340 Sep 19 03:39 test_ks-test_cf-hf-1-Statistics.db

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22 Sep 19 03:39 test_ks-test_cf-hf-1-Index.db

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16 Sep 19 03:39 test_ks-test_cf-hf-1-Filter.db

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 89 Sep 19 03:39 test_ks-test_cf-hf-1-Data.db

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 46 Sep 19 03:39 test_ks-test_cf-hf-1-CompressionInfo.db
```

1. When i am trying to export this data into MySql using below command, I see data is getting exported in non-readable format. I mean i am not able to see data which i have inserted in cassandra.

`./dse sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb --username testuser --password mysql123 --export-dir /var/lib/cassandra/data/test_ks/test_cf --table <table_name> --columns 'col1,col2' --input-fields-terminated-by '\t';`

where,
`--export-dir /var/lib/cassandra/data/test_ks/test_cf` is the path where data files gets created.

Could you please guide me where exactly I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance,
Santosh

Comment: What DSE version are you running? Have you used Thrift or CQL to create your keyspace and insert data?

Comment: Thanks. DSE 3.0 and i have used CQL to create keyspace and insert data.

Comment: I have achieved this using pentaho kettle. Looks like it is not possible to export data from cassandra to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of Sqoop in DSE allows for import, not export of data. You could also use the [Copy](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) cmd that'll export data into a csv file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But i was trying to export data from Cassandra to Mysql directly without using any mediator such as copy.